# Generation of Digital modulated waves using 555

Tags: pwm, 555, multivibrator

I am confused why there is ppm and digital modulated wave occur at 555 output, when 5th pin is given a triangular signal, instead of connecting it to 0.01uF capacitor. Please tell me which wave (PPM or PWM)  comes in what configuration of timer 555( monostable or astable)

Comment: In which configuration 555 is used is necessary to know. Rather than speculating and not providing a schematic raises doubt and would not yield any answers from the forum.

Comment: Its totally dependent on the circuit of the 555 timer, and how its wired.  I'd suggest you study up on how a 555 timer works

Comment: In monostable configuration. I am really sorry for not mentioning the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pin 5 of the '555 timer is its control pin (which sets the upper limit of the capacitor charge waveform).   Applying a random signal to this pin disturbs the accurate timing of the astable (oscillator) configuration, and is sometimes useful
to prevent forcing of an accidental resonance, by causing a variation
of the output frequency.

A periodic signal applied to pin 5 can also cause the
oscillator to lock onto the applied signal, causing frequency division
or multiplication (it's called 'pulse locking').

If (as is common) the negative power pin is GND, a bypass capacitor on pin 5
can inhibit accidental pulse triggering due to power supply noise.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 5 (control pin) is directly connected to the internal voltage divider used by the upper and lower comparators.

[image]

Normally you want these upper and lower voltages to be steady and free from any spikes or glitches. A small capacitor (0.01uF) is connected between pin 5 and ground.

The 555 will still work if you don't connect this capacitor but it may produce the odd pulse of a different period.

If you apply a voltage to pin 5 (usually AC coupled) you change the point at which the timing capacitor has to charge up to or down to in order to switch the output on or off. This directly effects the on and off periods producing a pulse width type modulation.